# Какую модель ML лучше применить для того, чтобы узнать какие features влияют на результат

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, feature-engineering

Коллеги, здравствуйте!

Хотел бы посоветоваться какую лучше модель ML применять, чтобы узнать влияние features на результат. У меня имеется датасет из финансовых показателей (X) (активы компании, собственный капитал, кредиторская и дебиторская задолженность, выручка, чистая прибыль, издержки и т.д.) и как результат (Y) компания стала банкротом или не стала банкротом.

Я применял XGBooster, но при разных разных параметрах в модели ( к примеру при смене importance type) были совершенно разные features.

Может есть какие-то ML библеотеки/модели, которые могли бы помочь определить какие имеено features влияют сильнее, а какие слабее, а может быть каие-то вообще не влияют...

Заранее спасибо за любые советы, ссылки, рекомендации!

Comment: Я бы начал [отсюда](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Буду изучать!

Comment: Можно попробовать разные бустинги и пересечь их по важным признакам, возможно это даст лучший результат, чем соло модель

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший пакет по этой теме "RandomUniformForest". Тема широко раскрыта с необходимыми примерами, функциями и графикой. 
Удачи

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите (тупо) использовать готовые, кем-то написанные программы, то можно начать и с библиотеки. Ну, а если хотите действительно понять "что, к чему и почему" -  то лучше начинать с того, что-бы разобраться как вообще к этой задаче можно подойти. Тогда многое станет понятным не только в данной теме, но и в ML вообще.

Написано на эту тему предостаточно. Для начала (если не углубляться в учебники) могу порекомендовать, например,

https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-engineering-techniques-9a57e4901545

https://habr.com/ru/company/jetinfosystems/blog/470622/

https://habr.com/ru/post/264915/

https://towardsdatascience.com/automated-feature-engineering-in-python-99baf11cc219

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/feature-selection-python

https://habr.com/ru/company/aligntechnology/blog/303750/

Потом, если "зацепит" и захотите углубляться - придется изучать  такую тему, как сравнение и выбор моделей, применяемых при обучении. Но эту уже "следующий уровень".

Comment: Использование программ/пакетов требуют много ума и опыта. Тупо можно только говорить о них не зная и не используя...